# Value Javascript to JSON in ASP.NET CORE MVC project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I try a lot of different solutions but i don't understand why my program doesn't work.
I just want take a value Javascript in my controller.

My Controller

```
 public JsonResult TestFunction (string FName)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            result = "Ok"
        });
    }
```

The Javascript in the View

```
 @section scripts{


<script type="text/javascript" >



    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#btnClick").click(function () {

            var f = {};
            f.data = JSON.stringify({FName: "FRANK" });
            f.type = "POST";
            f.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            f.url = '@Url.Action("TestFunction", "Home")';
            f.success = function (data) {
                alert(f.data);

            };
            f.error = function (response) {
                alert("failed");

            };
            console.log(f.data);
            $.ajax(f);
        });

    });




</script>
```

}

And or finish Html

I don't understand where is my mistake. 
Thanks.

Comment: No where have you set `data` in your `f` object

Comment: @StephenMuecke +1 And declare `data` with `var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `application/json` as `contentType`, try steps below:

1. Define ViewModel

   ```
   public class ViewModel
   {
       public string FName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Controller Action

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult TestFunctionViewModel([FromBody]ViewModel vm)
   {
       return Json(new
       {
           result = "Ok"
       });
   }
   ```
3. Request

   ```
           var f = {};
       f.data = JSON.stringify({FName: "FRANK" });
       f.type = "POST";
       f.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       f.url = '@Url.Action("TestFunctionViewModel", "Home")';
       f.success = function (data) {
           alert(f.data);

       };
       f.error = function (response) {
           alert("failed");

       };
       console.log(f.data);
       $.ajax(f);
   ```

   **Edit**

If you need `string FName` parameter, try steps below:

1. Add `[FromBody]`

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult TestFunction([FromBody]string FName)
   {
       return Json(new
       {
           result = "Ok"
       });
   }
   ```
2. Request

   ```
       var f = {};
       f.data = '"FNameTet"';
       f.dataType = "json",
       f.type = "POST";
       f.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       f.url = '@Url.Action("TestFunction", "Home")';
       f.success = function (data) {
           alert(f.data);

       };
       f.error = function (response) {
           alert("failed");

       };
       console.log(f.data);
       $.ajax(f);
   ```

   Note, that `'"FNameTet"'`